# FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: mkdir(): Read-only file system

Tags: php, nginx, manjaro

i'm running `nginx 1.16.1` with `php 7.4.0` on `Manjaro KDE 18.1.4`.

I have a quite similar setup on pure `arch Linux arm` where the following setting runs without problems.

I tried to setup an yii2 project which shows me the following error when entering `ig-net.at`:

> The directory is not writable by the Web process

or

> Failed to create directory "/usr/share/nginx/html/ig-net/runtime":
>   mkdir(): Read-only file system

The nginx error log shows the following error:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Read-only

The html folder, where the website is located is under `/usr/share/nginx/html/` and changed permissions accordanly

```
chmod -R g+w /usr/share/nginx/html/
chgrp -R http /usr/share/nginx/html/
chown -R http /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Both processes of nginx and php-fpm are running with `http` user.

`ps aux | grep nginx` and `ps aux | grep php-fpm` return the following:

```
root      6294  0.0  0.0  11868  1252 ?        Ss   15:33   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;
http      6295  0.0  0.0  12496  4352 ?        S    15:33   0:00 nginx: worker process

root      3393  0.0  0.3  88140 26844 ?        Ss   14:15   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/php-fpm.conf)
http      3395  0.0  0.2  92988 19512 ?        S    14:15   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
http      3396  0.0  0.2  92988 19776 ?        S    14:15   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
```

the nginx config file looks like this

```
user http;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite /.* /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name ig-net.at;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/ig-net/web;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite /.* /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to create a folder with in the terminal with the `http` user and it worked without any problems.

So what is the problem with the web process not working correctly?

Thanks,
Luc

Comment: Found a similar problem [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/996397/failed-to-open-stream-read-only-file-system-when-trying-to-create-file-outsid); QUICK FIX: moved the website to /srv/http/ . It seems like the `http` user/group is only allowed to write there.

Answer (score 1):

My guess why user `http` only writes in `/srv/http` is that it is the user's default home dir.

See:

```sh
# grep http /etc/passwd
http:x:33:33::/srv/http:/usr/bin/nologin
```

Comment: thats true; but why does the above settings work on arch linux arm and with manjaro it doesn't?

Comment: I wish I knew. I played around a bit, but couldn't figure it out. Especially, as `chown` for other users successfully does the job...